# Access VBA: using `do while` loop to update a recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, updates, do-while

I would like to get a result using a `do while` loop. 
However, my result gives only one record...

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Move through `rs` (record-set) records
2. Check if a value in `rs` is equal to `rs2`
3. If so, copy the `username` from `rs` to `rs2`
4. Move to the next record

   ```
   Do While Not rs.BOF                                  ' No of records in rs     
       Do While Not rs2.EOF                             ' No of records in rs2          
           If Trim(rs2![pic_no]) = Trim(rs![pic]) Then            
               rs![UserID] = rs2![NEW_USER]
               rs2.MoveNext
               rs.Update   
           Else
               rs2.MoveNext
               rs.Update    
           End If
       Loop          

       rs.MovePrevious
       rs.Update
   Loop
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Do While Not rs.EOF                                  ' No of records in rs
    Do While Not rs2.EOF                             ' No of records in rs2
        If Trim(rs2![pic_no]) = Trim(rs![pic]) Then
            MsgBox rs!UserID
            rs.Edit
            rs.Fields("UserID") = rs2![NEW_USER]
            rs.Update
        End If
    rs2.MoveNext
    Loop
rs2.MoveFirst
rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
rs2.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

But why don't you simply use an update statement?
Say you have two tables called TableUser (table you tefer to in rs) and TableNewUser (table you refer to in rs2).
Your update statement would like like:

```
UPDATE TableUser, TableNewUser
SET TableUser.UserID = TableNewUser.NEW_USER
WHERE TableUser.pic = TableNewUser.pic_no;
```

Much easier. You can put this update statement in VBA code too (if there's a need/reason to do so).

Comment: Really thanks for your help. The update statement is much easier. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Alan!  Incidentally you picked a good day to join, today is Microsoft Access's 25th Birthday since version 1.0 was released Nov 13, 1992.  :-)